# Does the amount of time that a Pokémon stays in a gym affect the points received for that gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Does the amount of time that a Pokémon stays in a gym relevant to the gym's points received?

Imagine that I have two pokemon in two different gyms. My two gym ranks are the same.

- When someone else defeats my Pokémon, do I earn (along with the maximum of 50 coins per day) any gym experience?
- If Pokémon A is in that gym for 5h and Pokémon B is in another gym for 10h, will I get more gym experience in gym B than in gym A?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Pokemon will generate 1 gym experience point for every minute it is sitting in the gym.

Therefore, Pokemon A that is in a gym for 5 hours will generate 300 gym experience points, and Pokemon B, with 10 hours, will generate 600 gym experience points.

Gym experience, in this context, is the experience that is used when moving from a bronze to a silver, or a gold gym badge.

When your Pokemon faints in battle, you will no longer generate any more gym experience, and no bonus is granted if your Pokemon is defeated.

More on this [here](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2017-08-10-pokemon-go-gym-badges-bronze-silver-gold-4819)